# Why this jQuery selector does not work for me?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to start an action everytime anything on the webpage else than specific object is clicked (menu "tree horizontal lines" button with class called "navbutton"), like this:

```
<div class="test">
    <nav id="menu" class="pdng-lr">
        <div class="navbutton">
            <span class="top"></span>
            <span class="middle"></span>
            <span class="bottom"></span>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu .navbutton
{
    display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (orientation: portrait)
{
.pdng-lr
{
    padding:0px;
}

#menu .navbutton
{
    display:block;
    width:25px;
    height:38px;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-left:calc(100% - 40px);
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#menu .navbutton span
{
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    min-height:6px;
    width:100%;
    margin:2px 0px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.15s linear;
    -moz-transition:all 0.15s linear;
    -o-transition:all 0.15s linear;
    transition:all 0.15s linear;
}

#menu .navbutton .top
{
    margin-top:6px;
}
}
```

I thought this script could work:

```
jQuery('div:not(".navbutton")').click(function(){
    // just to test if it works
    alert();
});
```

...but it does not: when I click on the .navbutton it still fire up the action anyway (alert window opens up)!

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code or how to make it work?

I try to make it as simple as possible on jFiddle but it still doe snot work even like that, see: https://jsfiddle.net/eygka3cn/3/

Comment: could you provide the css code that comes with it, please?

Comment: Now the CSS section of the relevant objects is in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is `div:not(.navbutton)`. `<div class="test">` triggers the `click` event, since it's a `div` without a `.navbutton` class bound to it. And `.test` is the parent of `.navbutton`.

You have some options:

- add `.test`, in your `not` selector
- make a click to `.navbutton` to stop propagating the event, as such

```
jQuery('.navbutton').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/0r2u5x1y/

Comment: Your code example works! Now only to know how to finetune it to replace that "everything else" ('div:not(".navbutton")') being "html" (as I want absolutelly anything else triggers the action, not just divs, even the empty white place on the page without any object at all, "html" would did that!) - can this be done too somehow? :-)

Comment: @fafa sure :) try replacing `div` with `*` in your selector

Comment: nah, just added html to the bunch, so now it is like 'html, div:not(".navbutton")' - works! :-) But * works too, so I switch to that as it is less of code, haha, thank you! BTW when I look at what I did prior to my question here, I really was missing just that very important part of "e.stopPropagation();", I did not even know about it, so you learned me something new here too. (as I wa smistakenly trying to use "return false" which is for each() thinking it could work even for this)

Comment: @fafa dom events can turn one real mad, real quick :D preventDefault and stopPropagation are life savers

Comment: ah, yea, but I have another problem now: would you like to solve that one for me too, please? :-D In fatc, the action that is fired up is to make a div from display:none to display:inline-block, but for some reason it stopped working now.

Comment: @fafa been a while since I've used jQuery, but I think `return false` does the same thing as `e.preventDefault()`, which is to be used to cancel the default behavior of an element. Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/0m73qdua/13/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254814/discussion-between-julien-duris-and-fafa).